# Find the possible values for two equations

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, equation

```
2x + 4y + 6z = 1200
x + y + z = 300
```

how can I find the possible `x`, `y`, `z` *integer* values in a c# method?, I am trying to find a better solution instead of using *brute force* **nested for loops** since it is not a good solution.

```
public List<Tuple<int, int, int>> Calculate()
{
    var result = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
    int maxValue = 300;

    for(int i = 0; i< maxValue; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < maxValue; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < maxValue; k++)
                if (i + j + k == maxValue && 2 * i + 4 * j + 6 * k == 1200)
                    result.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(i, j, k));

    return result;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please review the section [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And add the code you have tried.

Comment: You're looking to solve a system of linear equations, full answers to this are way out of scope for Stack Overflow as it's surprisingly hard (to code a solver to this, not to solve it mathematically). I recommend you just use an external package designed for this, like [Math.NET (numerics)](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/), it can [solve linear equation systems](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/LinearEquations.html). FYI you're probably going to get downvoted, as it seems like you haven't actually tried anything, which is a prerequisite for a good question

Comment: Thank you. yes I tried to find a formula to solve other equations that have another x-y-z values, So it is a linear equation

Comment: It's not difficult to code per se, It's difficult to code in an efficent way. Because the trivial solution  consists in just to invert a Matrix. If the Matrix is an 10000* 10000 Matrix this is a problem, but for 2 * 2 Matrix we can get it easily by inverting without futher optimization. (At least with the further assumption that all the equations are linearly independent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, having

```
2x + 4y + 6z = 1200
x + y + z = 300
```

you can put it as

```
x + 2y + 3z = 600
x + y + z = 300
```

subtract 2nd from the 1st and you get

```
y + 2z = 300
```

or

```
y = 300 - 2z
```

Since `x = 300 - y - z` we can put it as

```
x = 300 - y - z =
  = 300 - (300 - 2z) - z =
  = 300 - 300 + 2z - z =
  = z
```

Finally, for the *arbitrary* `z` (which is *free variable*)

```
x = z
y = 300 - 2 * z;
```

Possible **c#** code:

```
private static (int x, int y, int z) Solution(int x) => (x, 300 - 2 * x, x);
```

**Demo:**

```
string solutions = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
  .Range(0, 10)
  .Select(x => Solution(x)));

...

// 10 solutions for x = 0..9 
string solutions = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
  .Range(0, 10)
  .Select(x => Solution(x)));

Console.Write(solutions);
```

**Outcome:**

```
(0, 300, 0)
(1, 298, 1)
(2, 296, 2)
(3, 294, 3)
(4, 292, 4)
(5, 290, 5)
(6, 288, 6)
(7, 286, 7)
(8, 284, 8)
(9, 282, 9)
```

If you are looking for *non-negative* solutions only (you've mentioned *probabilities* in the comments for the code), then use `x` in `[0..150]` range:

```
(0, 300, 0)
(1, 298, 1)
(2, 296, 2)
...
(148, 4, 148)
(149, 2, 149)
(150, 0, 150)
```

**Edit:** your `Calculate()` method improved:

```
public static List<Tuple<int, int, int>> Calculate() {
  var result = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
  const int maxValue = 300;

  int start = Math.Max(150 - maxValue / 2, 0);

  for (int x = start; ; ++x) {
    int y = 300 - 2 * x;
    int z = x;

    if (y < 0 || x > maxValue)
      break;

    result.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(x, y, z));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. You are right for this question.  I tried to find a formula to solve other equations which has different x-y-z values, in this case should I always find a equation like you mentioned above? x = z and y = 300 - 2 * z;

Comment: @Alper: the solutions depend on what different equations are; the method (variables elimination), however, is the same. Here you have `151` (`x = 0, 1, ..., 150`) *non negative* solutions in the `(x, 300 - 2 * x, x)` form. Different equations (say, `4x + 8y + 6z = 1800` and `x + 2y + 3z = 600`) can well have different, but *linear* forms

Comment: thank you. I appreciate your solution. Actually this was a part of my problem mentioned here: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351969/algorithm-to-decide-product-quantity-values-in-a-purchase) Could you please sugggest an algorithm when you have time? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Alper if you want a general solution for generic 2*3 system of equations try to give my answer a try.

Answer (score 0):

**Math Theory**

If you want a general method you should use some Linear Algebra theory.
Let's rewrite the equations in matrix form as A(x,y) + bz = c,
where:

A: is the matrix that contains the coefficents of the x,y coordinates
A = (2,4,1,1)

b = (6,1) (transposed) is the vector containing the z coefficents.

c = (1200, 300) (transposed) is the vector containing the constant terms.

then (x,y) = AInverse * (c - bz). That is a function of z (Let's say f(z)). So for every z you obtain a valid solution: (f(z),z). f(z) is a vector of 2 components.

*Note*
If A is not invertible because the equations (rstricted to x and y) are linearly dependent (i.e. the 2 equations are the "same" equation in x and y), this method fails.

**Code**

We can code that like that:

**Step1**
We must code the Matrix2x2. I do it from scratch now, but you maybe want to use some framework if you really need in production:

```
public record struct Matrix2x2 (float A00, float A01, float A10, float A11)
{
    public float Determinant => A00 * A11 - A01 * A10;
    public Matrix2x2 Invert() => Determinant != 0
            ? 1 / Determinant * new Matrix2x2() { A11 = A00, A00 = A11, A01 = -A01, A10 = -A10 }
            : throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot Invert this matrix");

    public static Matrix2x2 operator *(Matrix2x2 a, float number) => new()
    {
        A00 = a.A00 * number,
        A01 = a.A01 * number,
        A10 = a.A10 * number,
        A11 = a.A11 * number,
    };
    public static Matrix2x2 operator *(float number, Matrix2x2 a) => a * number;
    public static Vector2 operator *(Matrix2x2 a, Vector2 vector)
    {
        var x = a.A00 * vector.X + a.A01 * vector.Y;
        var y = a.A10 * vector.X + a.A11 * vector.Y;
        return new(x, y);
    }
}
```

**Step2**
We must encode the equation. We need the Matrix A, the z coefficents and b, and the vector c of constant terms:

```
public delegate Vector3 SolutionSpace(float z);

public static class EquationHelper
{
    public static SolutionSpace SolveEquation(Matrix2x2 equationMatrix, Vector2 b, Vector2 c) => z =>
    {
        var v = equationMatrix.Invert() * (c - z * b);
        return new Vector3(v.X, v.Y, z);
    };
}
```

**Note:** The object returned from this function is the solution space, that depends from 1 parameter (the z value). So we could see it as a function that maps (float z) => (x(z), y(z), z) that in c# is a delegate that returns a Vector3 and takes in input a float.

**Usage**

```
var A = new Matrix2x2(2, 4, 1, 1);
var b = new Vector2(6, 1);
var c = new Vector2(1200, 300);
var solution = EquationHelper.SolveEquation(A, b, c);
foreach(var z in Enumerable.Range(-10, 21))
    Console.WriteLine(solution(z));
```

**Output**

[image]